# How to get the difference for the last event from two Windows?

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

We get the events from IoT hub as input, format is:

[
   {

```
  "events":[
     {
        "key":"Test1",
        "value":1345.2270720045908
     },
     {
        "key":"Test2",
        "value":1882.9263119959833
     }
  ],
  "EventProcessedUtcTime":"2016-06-29T08:39:53.9293808Z",
  "PartitionId":2,
  "EventEnqueuedUtcTime":"2016-06-29T08:39:18.7320000Z",
```

},
   {

```
  "events":[
     {
        "key":"Test1",
        "value":1456.6747534295491
     },
     {
        "key":"Test2",
        "value":1785.4095907491446
     }
  "EventProcessedUtcTime":"2016-06-29T08:49:53.9450060Z",
  "PartitionId":2,
  "EventEnqueuedUtcTime":"2016-06-29T08:49:19.0810000Z"
```

}
   .........................
]

Every 10 mins, we got a batch of values from IoTHub. we want to get the “**Test1**” difference for each hour.
Like the **Test1** last value in 3:00 – 4:00 is **600**, the last value in 4:00 – 5:00 is **800**, so the **difference** is **800 – 600 = 200**, which is we want.

First,  we want use the **TumblingWindow** with **1hour** duration, get the Last Value from the current value, and get the **Pervious Window Last value,** then use the current last value – previous value, but we **did not get the Previous Last Value succeed, so is anyway to get the LastValue in Previous Window?**

Second, we want to use the **HoppingWindow** with Duration is **60Min**, **overlap is 10min with previous window**, then we use the **TopOne()** with time stamp by ***  **asc** and **desc** to get the **First** and **Last** value , then get the **difference**, but did not get we wanted, get more than two values during one hour.

And I found that we **cannot use more WITH keyword in the query**, so it is not convenient, we get the Value from the Events, we need use the **CrossApply Get Elements(Input.Events)** get all events, use “**WITH**”  we use **LAG(Value)** function to get the previous value, but we **cannot use the LAG(events.arrayvalue.value),** it does not supported, so we want to use another query, also does not supported.

**So is there any way we can use to get the last value in two window difference? So if you have a solution, thanks so much!**

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the following statement is partially true:

> And I found that we cannot use more WITH keyword in the query, so it
>   is not convenient, we get the Value from the Events, we need use the
>   CrossApply Get Elements(Input.Events) get all events, use “WITH” we
>   use LAG(Value) function to get the previous value, but we cannot use
>   the LAG(events.arrayvalue.value), it does not supported, so we want to
>   use another query, also does not supported.

Although you can only use a single `WITH` keyword, you can create multiple steps as follows:

```
WITH 
    FirstStep AS (SELECT * FROM Input),
    SecondStep AS (SELECT * FROM FirstStep)

SELECT * INTO Output FROM SecondStep
```

> First, we want use the TumblingWindow with 1hour duration, get the
>   Last Value from the current value, and get the Pervious Window Last
>   value, then use the current last value – previous value, but we did
>   not get the Previous Last Value succeed, so is anyway to get the
>   LastValue in Previous Window?

You'll first need to flatten the input so it can be used together with the `LAG` and `LAST` keywords. You are already doing this with the CrossApply.
I'm assuming you want the 'SUM' of the values here, but you can change the aggregate function when you need something else.

```
HourlyAggregate AS SELECT 
   key,
   SUM(value) AS value
FROM CrossAppliedStep
GROUP BY key, TumblingWindow(hour, 1)
```

You should then be able to look back into the stream to get the previous value

```
LookBack AS SELECT
    key, 
    LAST(value) OVER (PARTITION BY key LIMIT DURATION(hour, 1)) AS previous_value,
    value AS current_value
FROM HourlyAggregate
```

Then  calculating the delta is easy

```
SELECT 
    key,
    value - previous_value AS delta
INTO Output
FROM LookBack
WHERE Key = 'Test1'
```

> Second, we want to use the HoppingWindow with Duration is 60Min,
>   overlap is 10min with previous window, then we use the TopOne() with
>   time stamp by * **asc and desc to get the First and Last value , then
>   get the difference, but did not get we wanted, get more than two
>   values during one hour.

This is the correct output, HoppingWindow of 10 minutes, will output a record every 10 minutes, but with the data of the last 60 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the hint that only one 'WITH' statement is possible